# Is it possible to implement saving changes to child objects in hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have such entities:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(of = {"id", "type", "hostId"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "hostId", "player"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@TypeDef(
        name = "pgsql_enum",
        typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class
)
public class ContentPlayer implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "Content_id")
    private Content content;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "player_id")
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private Player player;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "translation_id")
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private Translation translation;

    @Length(max = 155)
    @NotNull
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private String hostId;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private TranslationType translationType;


    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime updatedByPlayer;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime createdByPlayer;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contentPlayer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private Series series;
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(of = {"id", "seasons"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "episodesTotal", "seasons"})
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Series {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private int lastSeason;

    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private int lastEpisode;

    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private int episodesCount;

    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private int episodesTotal;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private LocalDate nextEpisode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "series", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private Set<Season> seasons = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private ContentPlayer contentPlayer;

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(of = {"id", "number"})
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id", "number"})
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Season {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private int number;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "season", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(Views.FullContent.class)
    private Set<Episode> episodes = new LinkedHashSet<>();;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "series_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Series series;

}
```

When I try to save the ContentPlayer with all child entities - everything goes fine, but if I want to add / change some data in the child entity - this leads to an error, although I indicated the cascade.
Error Example:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.core.entities.content.Season.series -> com.core.entities.content.Series;
```

Is it possible to implement saving changes to child objects? Adding each child object individually is not really appropriate.

Comment: You should show the code on how you read and change the ContentPlayer and assign it a Series but these mappings are very strange: how can you have a sequence on Series when it uses that value as the foreign key to ContentPlayer, and ContentPlayer has a similar chicken/egg issue with its ID and series reference mapping. One side needs to set an ID value, the other side just needs to use it. I don't know if that relates to your issue, but I don't see how you can 'add' in a relationship with the mappings this way, as it affects the primary keys which are immutable within entities.

Comment: @Chris Good afternoon, thank you for your time. Indeed, the data parser I used did not set the primary key for series when updating data if it already existed. You helped solve my problem.